# asp.net core delay on IIS contrary to IIS express

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

After I had deployed my first razor page site to IIS Ive been reported about weird delay in response. Very important to understand that it's closed environment without Internet access. During my research I figured out that deployed page prefer WWW resources rather than locals, and this actually is my problem, when it stuck there trying WWW where it isn't. Also Ive noticed that somehow my development with IIS express knows how to create html pages when they load ONLY LOCAL resources contrary to html pages on IIS.

[HTML pages difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMUJ3.png)

so the question is how can I configure asp.net core / IIS to create HTML pages that uses local resources and not remote ones?

Comment: "During my research I figured out that deployed IIS page prefer WWW resources rather than locals" is not a common way to describe issues in IIS terms. Please edit your question to include some screenshots.

Comment: As you are new here, you probably can only paste screenshots on another site, and link back here.

Comment: Find the relevant code in your views which prints those URLs. There's probably a difference because in IIS you deploy a release build.

Comment: Those links on IIS are surely valid only if you have access to CDN networks. They should be generated as part of release build I guess.

Comment: I found it, it was indeed the difference between development and production configuration within one of the schtmls. I don't know how I missed it before during my searches over the code. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is an Environment Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core. just need to configure it with Production in my case.

```
<environment include="Development, Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
```